# how to get around ArrayList.contains to use ==

Tags: java, arraylist

Having a problem where the underlying implementation of `.equals()` is treating 2 `Map`s as the same due to their key value pairs, and not their mem ref. While i know this is the correct procedure, i would still like to add them to another `ArrayList` according to unique reference.

```
String[] sortedStringOfDatesFromTempMaps = new String[dates.length];

List<Map<String, String>> tempTradeMap;

 for (int i = 0; i < sortedStringOfDatesFromTempMaps.length; i++) {
        String[] stringSplitArr = new String[2];
        stringSplitArr = sortedStringOfDatesFromTempMaps[i].split("=");

        for (int j = 0; j < tempTradeMap.size(); j++) {
            if (tempTradeMap.get(j).containsValue(stringSplitArr[0])
                    && tempTradeMap.get(j).containsValue(stringSplitArr[1])){

               if(!sortedMapList.contains(tempTradeMap.get(j))){
                    sortedMapList.add(tempTradeMap.get(j));
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is that `sortedMapList` should have the same number of elements that is passed in, in the first place. However as the contains impl is treating them equally they only add one. So if there are 5 elements, with 2 duplicate pairs, the final list will only contain 3 elements.

Comment: Is it the line "sortedMapList.contains(tempTradeMap.get(j))" that is causing you the trouble?

Comment: Yes it is, so i want it to check by reference, and not KV pairs.

Answer (score 4):

You can create child class of the `Map` implementaion you are using and overide `equals()` and `hashCode()`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a descendant of the kind of Map that you are using that overrode equals and hashcode, but that's overkill for what you want.

Instead write a method to do the containment test you want, like:

```
boolean containsExactly(Collection c,Object o) {...
```

In it you iterate over the items in the collection and check if any are identical to what you want to add using ==.